# How can I extract from an array of json object that is saved as text?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I would like to extract text out of a json that is part of an array, that is also unfortunately saved as text.

I have read only access to a postgres database that stores values from a live app through the tool Segment.

There's a column stored as text that holds an array of json objects, here's the structure:

```
[
  {"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2"},
  {"foo3":"bar3","foo4":"bar4"}
]
```

Again: the column is text, not saved as array, how can I convert then extract the json value of foo3 for example?

Comment: it seems no try from your end. however, if you don't have only read access to Postgres from which application/programming language you are running query?

Comment: Cast it to `json` or `jsonb` and use the JSON operators?

Answer (score 0):

This will convert text to jsonb

```
SELECT to_jsonb('[ {"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2"}, {"foo3":"bar3","foo4":"bar4"} ]'::text)
```

Read more here https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-json

Comment: Thanks, I actually found out that `to_jsonb(column::json)` solves the problem